# How can I get the list list of all Invoices,Estimates and Payments for a particular Customer in Quickbooks offline?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I want to provide a Customer `ListId` through QBXML and get the list of all Invoices, Estimates and Payments under that particular customer. What QBXML request would give me this? Please help.

Comment: qbXML, PaymentMethodRef not working in salesreceipt any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the QuickBooks OSR for all qbXML reference:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

There are also some additional samples here:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests

If you refer to the QuickBooks OSR, you'll find some really unsurprising qbXML requests named:

- InvoiceQueryRq
- EstimateQueryRq
- ReceivedPaymentQueryRq

An `InvoiceQueryRq` will give you invoices, an `EstimateQueryRq` will give you estimates, and so on and so forth. You may also want to check out `TransactionQueryRq` which queries all types of transaction at once (but be aware it will only give you summary data, and not detailed data like line items, etc. that the other more specific request types will give you).

The OSR will also show you that you can filter these queries to get back invoices, estimates, or payments for just a specific entity (e.g. a specific customer).

```
<EntityFilter>
  <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID>
  <!-- OR -->
  <ListIDWithChildren >IDTYPE</ListIDWithChildren>
</EntityFilter>
```

You can refer to the QuickBooks OSR link above for full qbXML reference and examples (look at the `XMLOps` tab in the OSR).